# How can I get rid of CORS error in Spring Boot with Angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I am facing CORS problems in my Spring Boot project in combination with Angular.

I am using the following code and annotated it as configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

In Angular I am adding this :

[image]

Unfortunately I am still getting this error:

[image]

None of them did the job.

Comment: `CORS` needs to be managed server-side, so adding those headers client-side to your request won't have any affect.

Comment: Try adding OPTIONS to the allowed methods

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually not your application's issue, but your browser's issue. Browsers make an OPTIONS request to application before sending actual data, to verify wheter they have access to make particular request or not.

To make it run what you can do is add OPTIONS into your code

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

or use extensions such as [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) tools etc.

Comment: Both not working, unfortunately. I keep getting that error.

Comment: try making .allowedOrigins("*");

Comment: Done, still getting stuck on the error.

Comment: This is the last hope , try putting @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") on controller class

Comment: This also didn't solve the problem. It's so strange. I've had this issue many times before and usually one of your answer solved the issue. This time it's different.

Comment: Well thats all i can help you with... :) let me know the solution. @GijsdeWert